# Deleted http referrers list for google maps api key

Tags: google-maps, google-developers-console

I was trying to change some settings with the google maps api key in the developer console and accidentally deleted the entire list of authorized sites, is there any history of the changes to the settings or any way to undo changes as this was a large list of websites.

Comment: I would suggest reaching out directly to Google Maps Platform support team via https://console.developers.google.com/google/maps-apis/support

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to get back the information you have deleted.  Its a good idea to take screen shots of things before you make any changes.

I believe there is a feature request somewhere for the ability to save settings.  Try clicking on the feedback button in the Developer console and sending them the request it wont help you now but if they add it it may help in the future.